# "npm start" fails when trying to call '.' in Cypress git repo

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, cypress

I'm trying to install a git repo for a Cypress course on Udemy. So far I've installed Node.js v15.14.0, NPM v7.10.0, and Visual Studios Code v1.55.2 on Windows 10 x64.

I was able to install and start Cypress successfully by itself in a folder on C:{User}\ using `npm install cypress`, then I was able to open it with `npx cypress open`.

The problem comes after I clone & install the following git repo: https://github.com/filiphric/udemy-cypress-course

I try to run `npm start` and get the following message:

> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file.

The command that appeared before this message was:

> ./node_modules/.bin/json-server --static . data.json -m middleware.js
> --config json-server.json -w

It's calling the json-server file in that directory, but I'm not sure what it's trying to do with the '.'.

I tried reaching out to the instructor already but they haven't gotten back to me, so I figured I'd see if my question could be answered here. npm looks like it's trying to start a json server in that repo but my machine doesn't know what to do with the dot '.' in that command.

Comment: Can you go to the package.json file in the folder and the part where it says script, what does the "start" bit say?

Comment: Reading the docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server#static-file-server You can see the argument after --static is the directory you want to serve. To test this command you can try without the . ./node_modules/.bin/json-server --static data.json -m middleware.js --config json-server.json -w

Comment: @ZackVT the "start" bit in the package.json file says "cd todomvc && npm start"

Comment: @DanielTate I got the same '.' error message when I tried running it as-is the way you posted it, so it must be referring to the first '.' in the command, not the one after --static. I tested it out instead by navigating to the node_modules\.bin folder and executing the command starting from "json-server".

When I tried running it from the .bin folder, I get a list of Options, Examples, and a URL to a Git repo for json-server, then the message "Invalid JSON config file: json-server.json". The only json-server.json file in the git project is in the folder "udemy-cypress-course\todomvc"

Comment: @DanielTate I get the same "Invalid JSON" error message when running the same command from the folder "udemy-cypress-course\todomvc\node_modules\.bin\"